# Is it possible to have a secure, restful authentication without SSL?

Tags: security, ssl

Is it possible to have secure authentication without using session, cookies and SSL ?

I have looked other protocols, such as SRP and Diffie-Hellman, but in the end you have to send the proof of key over the wire, and that would be vulnerable to "Man In The Middle" attacks...

Comment: SRP is not vulnerable to MITM. But what do you have against SSL/TLS?

Comment: The general issue with SSL/TLS is that it requires a 'trusted third party'. There is nothing wrong with trusted third parties in general, but right now we have the situation where the whole chain of trust revolves around cold hard cash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Without some pre-shared information, nothing is safe from the man-in-the-middle attack. You always need some pre-shared information to be secure against man-in-the-middle.** If you just want to be safe from passive eavesdropping, then pre-shared information is not needed.

The main reason why SSL works best is that you have the pre-shared security information - certificates. The web browsers are already bundled with it. For example, in Firefox look at Tools / Options / Advanced / Encryption / View certificates / Authorities, then select the certificate and click View.

You could of course have a different cryptographic protocol based on pre-shared information, so in principle it is possible without SSL. **But in current practice, the only pre-shared information bundled with web browsers are SSL certificates.**

Comment: Your point is valid, but you should avoid to use the expression "pre-shared keys". In SSL/TLS context, [PSK](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4279) is about pre-shared *symmetric* (or secret) keys (and is not nearly as widely used as PKI-based TLS authentication), not about the distribution of public keys via CA certificates. You're talking about CA certificates that are bundled and pre-trusted (CA don't "share" them with you as such, they give them away for you to trust them).

Comment: @Bruno, I agree, my terminology is not exact, I'm just speaking about principles. I edited my post a bit to reflect this (removed the term PSK). Thank you for your comment!

Comment: That is a very good explanation, i was always curious about why SSL is fundamentally more secure. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As long as there isn't some communication before the connection (privately exchange keys, so you can encrypt the message, etc.), nothing is secure without the use of SSL over the web.

Comment: even with SSL, you are not secure 100%.Take a look on SSL Strip.

Comment: @M.H: That is not an attack on SSL.

Comment: @M.H most browsers support STS these days.   Also +1,  ssl is required

Comment: Except for the SRP-protocol? (used for example in TLS)

Comment: This is not exact - SSL works just and only because it has pre-exchanged keys :-) See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For authentication only, any public-key-based cryptography could be an alternative. You can add custom HTTP request headers including a digital signature and a reference to the signer's certificate. This would be a totally proprietary approach, but it may suit your needs.